# Accent disappearing in the table when subscript is used

Tags: tables

The accent disappears when the T_{médio} is inserted, the letter disappears.

[image]

Comment: even without the accent you should avoid math italic for such words, here use `T_{\textrm{médio}}`

Comment: Okay, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even without the accent you should avoid math italic for such words, here use `T_{\textrm{médio}}` (you need `amsmath` package so that `\textrm` uses subscript size)